# How should model interactions be with different controllers

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii, model

I have a model named `Message`, which is an internal notification in my website.

I have a controller, `RegistrationController` that handles when a new person registers with my website. When this happens I send a `Message` to all users.

This is how the code involved looks like:

```
public static createMessage($receiver, $content)
{
    $message = new Message;
    $message->receiver = $receiver;
    $message->content = $content;
    $message->save(false);
}
```

It is called like this in the `RegistrationController.php`

```
   foreach($users as user)
       Message::createMessage($user->ID, $content);
```

---

**What is the best approach and that it won't violate mvc?**

1. Inside the Message model I add the `createMessage()` function. It doesn't require imports.
2. Or I create a `MessageController` and add that function inside? If I do version 2 then I need to `include MessageController` in the `RegistrationController`.
3. Any better idea.

Which version would produce better code that can better be maintained? Please quantify your answer to avoid opinions.

Answer (score 0):

Doing MVC is a style of programming.
There is no restriction where to put a logic. You can put it in Models or Controllers.

Which ever best suit your work style, use it.

I usually put in Controller the logics that interact with users through interfaces. (Get values from interfaces)

And put in Models the logics that help business rules. (Do things with the value from interface and database)

If you decide to put your Message logic as Controller, you do not need to include MessageController.

But make sure in the /config/main.php you include this:

```
'application.controllers.*'
```